# Number of distinct Subsets to a Set that has repeated values

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is a very general question but I can't seem to get a nice way to compute it. For example, take the set $\{1,2,2,1\}.$ The subsets to this are $$\emptyset,\{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{1, 1\}, \{2,2\}, \{1,2,2\},\{1,1,2\}, \{1,2,2,1\}$$ for a total of $9$ distinct subsets. However, I don't see a clever way to compute the amount of subsets a set with repeated values has as there are. I know for a general set that doesn't have repeated values, the number of possible subsets is $2^{n}$ where $n$ is the number of terms in the set. I've tried experimenting with the choose functions and such but I don't seem to be able to get a nice result. May I have some help for computing the number of subsets to a general set $\{a_1, \cdots, a_n\}$ where some $a_i$ is repeated an arbitrary amount of times? If there isn't a nice closed form, what about my example? Would there be a nice way to count the amount of subsets to that? Thanks in advance..

Comment: In your example you can have either 0, 1, or 2 occurrences of '1' and 0, 1, or 2 occurrences of '2', so you have $3\times 3 = 9$ choices.  Can you see how to generalize this?

Comment: Hmm I think that's a really nice intuitive way to think about this. Yes I think I know how to generalize this! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that there are $2^n$ subsets of an $n$-element set is that we can choose to include $0$ or $1$ of the first element, $0$ or $1$ of the second, and so on. If we have a multiset with $n_k$ copies of item $k$, $k=1,2,\dots,m$ then we can include from $0$ to $n_1$ copies of the first item, from $0$ to $n_2$ copies of the second, and so on, so the number of sub-multisets is $$(n_1+1)(n_2+1)\cdots(n_m+1)$$