# Number of distinct subSEQUENCES to a set that has repeated values

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have tried searching for answers to this seemingly simple problem but I can't find any results. This is very similar to my [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132242/number-of-distinct-subsets-to-a-set-that-has-repeated-values) question about number of distinct subSETS to a set that has previous values. However, subsequences are different from subsets. If $S$ is a finite set of numbers, a subsequence of $S$ consists of some terms of $S$ in its original order. For example, using my example in my previous question, the subsequences to the set $\{1, 2, 2, 1\}$ will be $$\emptyset,\{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{1, 1\}, \{2,2\}, \{2,1\}, \{1,2,2\},\{1,2,1\}, \{2,2,1\} ,\{1,2,2,1\}$$ for a total of $11$ subsequences. However, unlike counting subsets, I don't find an intuitive way to count the distinct subsequences of $\{1,2,2,1\}.$ Some of the subsequences of $\{1, 2, 2, 1\}$ have the exact elements in them, except I'm not sure how to determine which subsequences will have other arrangements. (For example, $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{2, 1\}$ would be considered different subsequences, though they are considered the same subset.) May I have some help approaching this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please inform me if there isn't or is a nice way of computing the number of distinct subsequences to a set (as I don't think there's a nice way as of now).

Comment: Could I have some help?

Comment: I still do not have a result.

Comment: Do you have any comment on the answer or the context of the question?  You seem to have been quite insistent on getting help before.

Comment: I think I understand your answer, it's essentially to use the formulas $a_n = 2a_{n-1}$ and $a_n = 2a_{n-1} - a_{j-1}$ repetitively to count the total number of subsequences. Also, for reference, my question originates from the solution in the ARML Power Question 2004. The solution to the problem of finding the number of subsequences to $\{1, 2, 2, 1\}$ was simply to list all of them out, but I think I understand your way of finding a recursive formula for finding the number of subsequences. If I'm confused with anything, I will ask for further assistance. :)

Comment: It’s great to know the reference, thanks for providing it.  It’s worth pointing out that my solution is essentially identical to what’s stated in Question 4 Parts a and b in the ARML Power question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one has a very elegant recursive solution.  Let $s_1, \ldots, s_n$ be the elements of $S$ (in order of appearance).  Let $S[1\ldots k]$ denote the partial sequence $s_1, \ldots, s_k$.  Let $a_k$ be the number of **distinct** subsequences of $S[1\ldots k]$, and suppose we already have calculated the values of $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ (note that $a_0 = 1$ for the trivial subsequence).

- If $s_n$ is different from all elements of $S\setminus \{s_n\}$, then
  easily $a_n = 2 a_{n-1},$ since to get a subsequence of $S$ we
  either append $s_n$ to a subsequence of $S[1\ldots n-1]$ or we leave
  it as-is.  There are no duplicates within the first category or
  within the second category, and there is no intersection between the
  two since any subsequence containing $s_n$ cannot be a subsequence of
  $S[1\ldots n-1]$.  Hence in this case, $$a_n = 2a_{n-1}.$$
- If $s_n$ is equal to some previous $s_j$ with $j<n$, then we will
  have a non-trivial intersection, as exist some subsequences of
  $S[1\ldots n-1]$ that remain subsequences of $S[1\ldots n-1]$
  after we append $s_n$.  Still, we only need to count the number of
  such redundancies.

  Let $j$ be the highest index $j<n$ such that $s_j = s_n$.  Then any subsequence of $S[1\ldots n-1]$ that ends in $s_n$ must be a subsequence of $S[1\ldots j]$.  In fact the number of (distinct) such subsequences is exactly $a_{j-1}$: for any subsequence of $S[1\ldots j-1]$, appending $s_j$ gives a subsequence of $S[1\ldots n-1]$.  So we overcount by exactly $a_{j-1}$, which means that

$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} - a_{j-1}.$$

Let's work out this for your example $\{1,2,2,1\}$:
$$\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1, \\
a_1 &= 2 a_0 = 2, &\text{(first case)} \\
a_2 &= 2 a_1 = 4, &\text{(first case)} \\
a_3 &= 2 a_2 - a_1 = 6, &(s_3 = s_2) \\
a_4 &= 2 a_3 - a_0 = 11. &(s_4 = s_1)
\end{align}$$

It is relatively easy to turn this into a linear time algorithm (assuming that arithmetic is constant-time, which can be a strong assumption for an exponentially growing sequence), as the search for the highest matching index can be done very efficiently with hash tables.